# Cannot GET /*url*

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I was working on an admin panel so I decided to not repeat myself and made a file with the name of Admin.js with this code:

```
     <div className="admin-page">
       <div className="admin-bar">
          <ul>
             <li><NavLink to="/admin" activeClassName="is-active" exact> Dashboard </NavLink></li>
             <li><NavLink to="/admin/movies" activeClassName="is-active"> Movies </NavLink></li>
             <li><NavLink to="/admin/series" activeClassName="is-active"> Series </NavLink></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="admin-content">{this.props.renderData}</div>
    </div>
```

then added the other pages for example (AdminMovies.js):

```
const content = (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Link to="/"> Add a New Movie </Link>
        hello
    </React.Fragment>
)

const AdminMovies = () => (
    <AdminTemplate renderData={content} />
)
```

and it worked just fine when I go to it through the nav it renders perfectly, but when I try to access it by the url it give me the error

> Cannot GET /admin/movies

and I don't know why.

the route tree:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact />
                <Route path="/admin" component={AdminDashboard} exact />
                <Route path="/admin/movies" component={AdminMovies} />
                <Route path="/admin/series" component={AdminSeries} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: are you using webpack dev server

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm actually using create-react-app so I'm sure they set the historyfallback and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you probably don't have [server-side routing](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md) setup.

When you load `/` - your app, and all the JavaScript, which happens to include router logic gets downloaded to the browser. From there on, react-router handles the navigation on client-side. You never make another trip to the server (a bit over-simplified statement but this is not blog post to get into details).

When you try to load `/url` directly, the server has no idea how to handle this request. This is why you need to setup server side routing so your server understands the routes.

Here's how your restructured code would look like (not production ready code - just to give you an idea)

```
// routes
const App = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact />
        <Route path="/admin" component={AdminDashboard} exact />
        <Route path="/admin/movies" component={AdminMovies} />
        <Route path="/admin/series" component={AdminSeries} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
);

// client
<BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
</BrowserRouter>

// server (not the complete story)
<StaticRouter
    location={req.url}
    context={context}
>
    <App/>
</StaticRouter>
```

I'd suggest to read the documentation thoroughly since server side rendering will open up new issues as well. The documentation tells you how to deal with them.

Comment: but then what do I export to use at the ReactDom render call then?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked? It [answers](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/server-rendering.md#putting-it-all-together) your question.

Comment: I did but does that mean that I've to have a SSR code just for this? sorry I'm just pretty new to React. :)